# Android NDK: How do I rebuild the .APK file(s)?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, apk, android-install-apk, ndk-build

I'm building my NDK project on a Mac from the command line (Terminal). I am able to compile and link my "libmain" and I have been using Android Studio to install the built app on my phone.. or at least so I thought..

From what I can see, my .apk file is not changing at all when I run ndk-build.

That would mean that the same broken application is being installed on my phone over and over again even though I'm recompiling my source..

```
MacbookPro:android-TT admin$ find . -name "*.apk"
./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

The timestamps for the above .apk files never change when I do an ndk-build. I guess Android Studio must be responsible for building these?

Can ndk-build be used to create the .apk file(s) or should I be calling another utility to generate the .apk file(s) ?

I would have thought that Android Studio would have detected change in my libmain output and rebuilt the .apk file(s) but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd .. (to folder with AndroidManifest.xml)
android update project --name app --path . --target "android-14"
ant -v debug
```